# Как присвоить объекту css rule при указанном условии?

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation

Есть такая машина:

```
.car {
    position: relative;
    left: 320px;
    top: 245px;
    width: 150px;
    animation: mymove 5s;
}
```

И её перемещение:

```
@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}
```

Как исполнить это перемещение при указанном условии?
Т.е., например:

```
function timerAddition() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('timerAddition');
    obj.innerHTML--;

    if (obj.innerHTML < 20) {
        /*исполнить перемещение*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что мешает сделать так?

```
function timerAddition() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('timerAddition');
    obj.innerHTML--;

    if (obj.innerHTML < 20) {
        obj.style.animation = "mymove 5s";
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо. Я не знала как это правильно написать синтаксически

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите анимацию в отдельный css-класс, и по условию применяйте его к нужному элементу.